# Sniper team from different G-Worlds

Tags: planets, gravity

The metric system (SI units) is a base-10 measurement system based on the meter, kilogram and second.  But it is tied to earth.

A second, which historically was defined as 1/86,400 of a day, now defined as a fixed numerical value of the caesium frequency.  The meter is defined as the length of the path traveled by light in a vacuum in 1/299,792,458 of a second.  A newton is the force that would give a mass of one kilogram an acceleration of one meter per second per second.  So the metric system is tied to earth.

Civilizations from different planets would have different measuring systems, but the need for math with large and small quantities means advanced races probably would have a base-10 system.  (That may be a stretch, but it's an assumption I feel safe to make.)

Two individuals from different gravity worlds, a sniper from Earth (1G - increments of Earth gravity) and a 1.5G spotter forced to work together on a 1.2G world.  Obviously, they have their heights as a reference.

What would be the minimum information they would have to exchange to work as a functional sniper team?

Sniper uses rifle scope, and spotter uses their eyes (binocular vision with retinas that lengthen to zoom vision).  You can assume they can communicate in the same trading language and an artificial intelligence is available.  Target distance 1km to 1.5km.

Comment: You mean like unit conversion tables? Isn't this no different than asking how a sniper from the US military works with a sniper from France? Also, all those units have been redefined to be based on universal constants, both the second and most recently the kilogram. They can be determined based on the definition no matter where you are in the universe without any knowledge of Earth.

Comment: US military use the metric system so that they are compatible with NATO forces.  But the second is tied to Earth, hence the Newton is too.

Comment: No, it's not (at least not anymore). Your information is decades out of date. https://www.nist.gov/si-redefinition/introduction-redefining-worlds-measurement-system https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2019_redefinition_of_the_SI_base_units

Comment: @DKNguyen They have moved from [physical samples](https://www.vox.com/science-and-health/2018/11/14/18072368/kilogram-kibble-redefine-weight-science)  to constants, because the physical samples have changed marginally over time (Standard kg).  But different worlds would have different measurement systems.

Comment: Yes, but the answer still ends up being unit conversion tables. It's no different than converting between imperial and metric. If you transmitted to some aliens "this is what a meter is" they could figure it out in their units and just send you back a unit conversion. A universal constant is what it is, no matter where you are, regardless of what number or value you choose to ascribe to it. As long as you are consistent with the numbers, that's all that matters.

Comment: TLDR: It only works if the two individuals have trained and prepared to work together in this way. If they have not, then the benefits a sniper/spotter team is supposed to realize from the division of labor are impossible.

Comment: Why are people hating on this question so much?  Looks legit to me.

Comment: @Willk I didn't downvote, but there are some implicit assumptions in the question that are pretty spurious, if not demonstrably false.

Comment: A score of -4 for the _assumptions_ seems a bit excessive to me, but there you go. Offend the elite radix defence squad at your peril.

Comment: @StarfishPrime what the heck is a radix?

Comment: @MorrisTheCat latin for "root", hence the small red vegetable of (almost) the same name.

Comment: If they don't train together, they're not a fire team. Once they do train together, the first thing they figure out is unit conversions.  Thus, a sniper and a spotter will always be able to work together, regardless of how heavy their bullets happen to be for the same amount of mass on the world they were born on.

Comment: A number of answerers have taken noble stabs at this one, but this question needs a lot of work.  But i have faith it has the potential to be really good!  It's just really hard to see the question from here.

Answer (score 6):

Honestly, we *already* live in the future. Autotranslation of spoken words and conversion of distances, especially in the context of a limited and precise vocabuary, seems entirely practical by the time someone has mastered interstellar travel.

---

Alternatively:

> What would be the minimum information they would have to exchange to work as a functional sniper team?

"*This is called a 'lay-zor'. It has no windage, drop or coriolis issues, and does its own ranging and autofocussing.*"

> You can assume they can communicate in the same trading language and an artificial intelligence is available.

"*Tell your AI to kill that one over there in the red hat.*"

Comment: It's not the future until we have flying cars, just saying.

Comment: @MorrisTheCat people often complain about that, whilst wandering around with pocket supercomputers which can provide instant global communication and information on almost any topic known to humankind. Honestly, I think they're just ungrateful. And probably not the sort of people who could be trusted to fly, either.

Comment: Oh god yes. Flying cars are a HORRIBLE idea. Most humans in my urban environment shouldn't be trusted with the NORMAL kind. Certainly not while simultaneously attempting to operate their pocket supercomputer.

Comment: This is why we need to perfect the self-driving car.  Once we do that, the self-flying car will be safe to operate at the same time as your pocket supercomputer... that and make fusion doable,affordable, and environmentally safe enough that we can stop worrying about the fuel economy of flying (or lack thereof.)

Comment: @MorrisTheCat AI driven flying cars to free you up to use your handheld super computer.

Comment: @DKNguyen well it's not like I trust anybody ELSE to operate one...

Comment: @MorrisTheCat What if we made a copy of your mind and trapped it in a car to do nothing but drive for you? Are you the kind of person who would drive into a wall to commit suicide if that was your fate? if so, then that's probably the least trustworthy car to be driving itself.

Comment: @DKNguyen I actually spend a LOT of time playing driving games. I'm globally ranked in Forza Motorsport, so that's not QUITE the dire fate that you might expect.

Answer (score 4):

#### The sniper's team's jobs will be obsolete long before we can travel between stars.

The technology already exists to make self targeting rifles that are more accurate than nearly any human sniper, but in your more advanced civilization, this tech would easily be way beyond human limitations.  This means that the guy holding the gun IS the spotter, and the real sniper is the on-board AI.  The human operator will use a scope to key in a target, then the gun will use a onboard instruments to execute the shot relatively independent of the operator effectively functioning as a spotter/sniper team.

There is no language barrier because the computers make it so easy to interchange one language for another.  Also, when your shooter fires, he no longer needs to know exactly how many Meters or Kellicams away the target is.  His job is just to tag the targets and press a button.  The weapon's internal computers can be using whatever form of measurement they want.  It's not the operator's job to need to know that anymore.

#### A little bit of the hard science behind this kind of weapon system.

The below information is just what we can do with what technology exists today. For a space faring civilizations most of these things should all be trivial, miniaturized, and probably improved on more than once.

**Distance:** Laser rangefinders are nothing new.  Your gun can just needs to tap a potential target with a low-powered laser and use time to reflection to find its distance. Snipers already use this tech all the time.

**Wind Speed:** Computers can do this WAY better than a human.  Whereas a human can use the wind to make a single factor approximation about the wind conditions of his shot, a computer can use doppler radar or lidar backscattering to determine exactly what the wind is doing at every point between you and the target.  This means that if you are firing across a canyon, and there is an updraft in a particular spot between you and the target, the gun's sensors can detect that.

**Coriolis Effect:** This one would be REALLY hard for a human sniper on a new world because knowing your lat/lon no longer tells you what that means for the new world you are on, and all your training goes out the window.  But for the AI, your ship or satellite in orbit will act as your GPS telling your exact position, what direction you are facing, and spin rate of the planet so that your gun can compensate for these otherwise unknown factors.

**Atmosphere:** Another tricky one for human snipers, but easy for computers.  An optical sensor on your gun can tell exactly what gases are in the air through a process known as absorption banding because each gas absorbs a unique pattern of wavelengths in known proportions.  This tells your computer the exact drag conditions of your flight path.

**Gravity:** Another computer = better task.  If you have a 1 gram weight inside your gun attached to a high precision scale that says the weight is 1.21473 grams, then you know you are on a planet with 1.21473Gs.  You just key your gun to local gravity when you land on a new world and you are good to go.

**Tagging:** Tagging and tracking targets for prioritization used to be a seperate human job because computers did not understand image recognition well enough to do this.  Now that computers can, you can automate the tracking process so that your shooter can just key in targets, and the gun can use secondary wider-field optics to keep track of them while you assess other targets.

**Computation:** The math behind a ballistics shot is so easy that a 1940's computer could do it ([SEE ENIAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ENIAC)).  While the human mind struggles to consider more than 7 factors at once, a computer can track billions of simultaneous factors without forgetting to account for a single one.  Once you are ready to shoot, the onboard computer can plot dozens of trajectories faster than you can finish pulling the trigger.  Infact, your shooter should be able to queue up targets for the gun so that it can deliver those dozen kill shots in what looks like a burst of machine gun fire.

**Error Correction:** With much better instrumentation it is unlikely for a shot to ever miss, but what if your target sneezes right when you shot?  That's okay, smart bullets are also becoming a thing now.  Since your computer already knows what your target looks like, your bullet does too; so, it just corse corrects mid-flight for that perfect kill shot anyway.

In realty, we will probably see the role of the spotter disappear within many of our own lifetimes, not just as some far flung future sci-fi thing.

Comment: I don't agree with this at all. Those roles may CHANGE, but I don't think for a moment they're going to become obsolete. The spotter's job is to find and prioritize targets. The shooter's job is to develop the targeting solution and hit the target. Those roles are NOT going away no matter what kind of weapons are in use. The skills and processes required to execute them may change, sure.

Comment: @MorrisTheCat You are missing the point. There is no longer "developing a targeting solution".  That part is done now by the weapon itself.  With minimal development on already existing technologies, a shooter could even tag several targets, then press the trigger to rapidly fire a dozen pinpoint shots to hit a cluster of targets a km away.

Comment: They might even have self aiming/tracking bullets that can track the target as they move around. http://www.bbc.co.uk/newsbeat/article/32513006/self-aiming-bullets-developed-by-us-defence-agency-hit-moving-target

Answer (score 3):

So, there are a few things here.

First of all, base 10 is NOT a safe assumption. The only reason humans use base 10 is because evolution gave us ten fingers, and even WE don't use base 10 for everything, we use a lot of base 12 and base 16 too.

Second: all members of sniper/spotter teams are snipers. One member or the other may be the one actually handling the rifle versus the scope, but at least in any modern military thinking, both guys get exactly the same training. The difference is that a guy who can do math faster in his head winds up as the spotter and the guy who can keep his hand the steadiest will fire the rifle.

Third: Firing a sniper rifle is mostly a math problem. No matter what planet you're on, you need to know three things.

- How far away from your target you are.
- How much vertical deflection is going to be applied to the trajectory of your projectile by the force of gravity.
- How much horizontal AND vertical deflection is going to be applied to the trajectory of your projectile by
  environmental effects like wind, humidity, air pressure, and so
  forth.

The First and Third items will be different for every shot. The second is a fixed variable depending on what the force of gravity is on whatever planet you're on versus the amount of time it's going to take your projectile to get to the target.

That said, there are two possible answers here.

Option 1: You have a team of two soldiers from different planets who are part of a multi-civilization military organization. This means if they haven't trained together, at the very least BOTH have been trained to use a common system of reference that allows the spotter to tell the sniper how much vertical and lateral adjustment he needs to make to his scope to account for the variables I mentioned above. This is a pretty standard problem for all kinds of militaries that need to cooperate in the world and, for example, is the reason that air traffic control is always managed in English no matter where you are in the world.

Option 2: You have a team of two soldiers that have never worked together previously and have no common system of reference. In order to operate effectively as a sniper team, they would need to CREATE a common system of reference basically from scratch before they can do any shooting and, to be honest, under these conditions your 'spotter' individual would be of very limited utility to your earth sniper, telescopic vision or not, because this kind of shooting requires very accurate math, and two people trying to use different math are going to wind up with a lot of rounding errors, and that means missed shots.

Really the best your spotter is going to be able to do for your shooter is tap him on the shoulder and point at targets, and give VERY rough estimates of how far off his shots were if he misses.

Comment: Not sure where Base-12 and -16 are used, but Base-2 on computers.  But an advanced civilization would need a consistent math system to deal with large \$10^{18}\$ and small numbers \$10^{-18}\$, which is the strength of the metric system.  Option 2 seems more plausible.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat I'm not sure where you got this idea that base 10 is somehow superior mathematically, but it's not. Certainly there isn't anything 'less consistent' about hexadecimal notation compared to decimal notation.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat for base 12, look at your clock. For base 16, look at computers (hint: binary is used internally, but other abstractions are used at higher levels). Exponents work just fine with other bases, too. 2^20 for mega, 2^-20 for micro, for example. The fact that we don't generally use the latter doesn't mean that it is unusable.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat What you are trying to describe as base-10 is actually scientific notation. For example, floating point numbers on a computer could be thought of as something like scientific notation (with concessions to practicality) in base-2. Base refers to when you wrap around on numerals and start adding zeroes.

Comment: @Zwuwdz there's even such a thing as [floating point hexadecimal too](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_hexadecimal_floating_point), Not so common these days, because it isn't very useful to us or machines, but it still works.

Comment: @StarfishPrime well that's just witchcraft.

Comment: Also for base 12, look at the history of the English language...  Ever wonder why the "teens" don't start until 13?  Base 12 is also more useful in fractions, as it has more common factors than 10...  12 has 2, 3, and 4, so you can easily divide into halves, thirds, and quarters...  Dividing a decimal 10 into thirds results in 3.3333..., where cutting a dozen into thirds results in an even 4 (and quartering a dozen results in 3 instead of quartering ten resulting in 2.5).

Answer (score 2):

**Distance and drop.**

Besides gravity, they presumably will have an unfamiliar atmosphere on this world.  You might as well give them a rifle that neither is familiar with as well, loaded with weird osmium ammo.

You can have the spotter measure distance to targets, pacing them off.  Your sniper can watch thru the scope.

When spotter returns it has pictures it has taken of various marks it has made at known distances.  Sniper can see them thru the scope.  The pictures are marks in the spotters language that correspond to distance.  "Nicknames", it tells the sniper.  The sniper recently taught it about nicknames by giving it one.

Your sniper starts shooting.  The spotter will call out how far off each shot hits.

Your sniper calibrates the rifle empirically and experimentally, factoring in gravity, atmosphere and osmium bullets all with the same test shots.

The spotter goes back out when they are done and erases the targets and conceals the bullet marks.  It has done this before.

Comment: Don't forget windage. You've got drop(vertical) AND windage (lateral) drift on your projectile unless you've got no atmosphere moving around.

Comment: Also: I would upvote you twice if I could just for the last five words of your answer. That's some good stuff right there.